# nltk multi_kappa (Davies and Fleiss) or alpha (Krippendorff)?

Tags: python, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa, nltk

I'm using inter-rater agreement to evaluate the agreement in my rating dataset. I have a set of `N` examples distributed among `M` raters. Not all raters voted every item, so I have `N x M` votes as the upper bound.
So let's say the rater `i` gives the following votes the the `N` items, for a given `N=5` and `M=3`, where in the array at position `j` there is the `j-th` item:

```
rater[1] = [1,3,0,5,5]
rater[2] = [0,3,1,5,2]
rater[3] = [1,2,0,5,3]
```

where `0` meaning that the voter did not express any option about item in position `j`.
Now, I cannot use the Cohen's Kappa, since it requires to have almost two rathers, so I think to use the [Alpha Krippendorff](https://github.com/tousif/nltk-gae/blob/master/nltk/metrics/agreement.py#L304) of NLTK or the [multi-kappa](https://github.com/tousif/nltk-gae/blob/master/nltk/metrics/agreement.py#L296).

In my dataset

- Votes eventually can be sparse, i.e there can be items that have few votes hence like the worst case of

  ```
  rater[i] = [0, 0, ...,j, ..., 0]
  ```

so the item `j` could have just one vote by the rater `i` in the whole dataset.

- Each item must have at least one vote, hence there are no items with a zero array.
- The numbers of raters `M` is less than the numbers of items `N`, `M < N`.

Which is the best approach as for the NLTK [metrics](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.metrics.html) package implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56481245/inter-rater-reliability-calculation) and it was useful for my case so you probably check it out. Here's the possible solution for your dataset.

```
import krippendorff
data = [[1,3,0,5,5],
       [0,3,1,5,2],
       [1,2,0,5,3]]    

kappa = krippendorff.alpha(data)
print(kappa)
```

It works with Python 3.4+ and don't forget to install dependencies

```
pip install numpy krippendorff
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Abu for your solution!